# How to correctly setColor in a custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view like a crop view which is used in my app to define the cropping area. But the app crashes while inflating the view. May be I have not understood how to use the setColor correctly. I have tried using: `BoxPaint.setColor(AppShared.gResources.getColor(R.color.bwff_60))`, the app still crashed. Please tell me what all changes I should make in the code so that I'll be able to see the view.

**Logcat:**
[image]
[image]

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.md.areadectest"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutMain" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/width_320" android:layout_height="@dimen/width_240" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/preview">
        </SurfaceView>
            <FrameLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/layoutDetectArea" android:background="@color/blue" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <com.md.areadectest.AreaDetectorView android:id="@+id/viewDetector" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trigcount"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**View.java**

```
public class  AreaDetectorView extends LinearLayout {

    public static int Width;
    public static int Height;
    private static Paint BoxPaint = null;
    private static Paint BoxPaint2 = null;
    private static Paint TextPaint = null;
    private static Paint ArrowPaint = null;
    private static Path mPath = null;
    private static Rect mRect = null;
    private static int lastX, lastY = 0;
    private static boolean mBoxTouched = false;
    private static boolean mArrowTouched = false;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static int ArrowWidth = 0;

    public AreaDetectorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
//attrs was not there
    public AreaDetectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        if (!this.getRootView().isInEditMode()) {
            ArrowWidth =GetDisplayPixel(context, 30);
        }

        //InitDetectionArea();

        InitMemberVariables();
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    public static int GetDisplayPixel(Context paramContext, int paramInt)
    {
        return (int)(paramInt * paramContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5F);
    }

    public static void InitMemberVariables() {
        if (BoxPaint == null) {
            BoxPaint = new Paint();
            BoxPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            BoxPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
            //BoxPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            BoxPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            BoxPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.bwff_60));
        }
        if (ArrowPaint == null) {
            ArrowPaint = new Paint();
            ArrowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            ArrowPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.redDD));
            ArrowPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        }
        if (TextPaint == null) {
            TextPaint = new Paint();
            TextPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.yellowL));
            TextPaint.setTextSize(16);
            //txtPaint.setTypeface(lcd);
            TextPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        }
        if (mPath == null) {
            mPath = new Path();
        } else {
            mPath.reset();
        }
        if (mRect == null) {
            mRect = new Rect();
        }

        if (BoxPaint2 == null) {
            BoxPaint2 = new Paint();
            BoxPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);
            BoxPaint2.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
            //BoxPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            BoxPaint2.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            BoxPaint2.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.bwff_9e));
        }

    }

    public static void InitDetectionArea() {
        try {
            int w = Preferences.DetectionArea.width();
            int h = Preferences.DetectionArea.height();
            int x = Preferences.DetectionArea.left;
            int y = Preferences.DetectionArea.top;

            // ver 2.6.0
            if (Preferences.DetectionArea.left == 1
                    && Preferences.DetectionArea.top == 1
                    && Preferences.DetectionArea.right == 1
                    && Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom == 1) {

                w = Preferences.DisplayWidth / 4;
                h = Preferences.DisplayHeight / 3;

                // ver 2.5.9
                w = Width / 4;
                h = Height / 3;

                Preferences.DetectorWidth = w;    
                Preferences.DetectorHeight = h;   

                x = (Preferences.DisplayWidth / 2) - (w / 2);
                y = (Preferences.DisplayHeight / 2) - (h / 2);

                // ver 2.5.9
                x = (Width / 2) - (w / 2);
                y = (Height / 2) - (h / 2);

            }

            //Preferences.DetectionArea = new Rect(x, x, x + Preferences.DetectorWidth, x + Preferences.DetectorHeight);
            Preferences.DetectionArea = new Rect(x, y, x + w, y + h);

            Preferences.gDetectionBitmapInt = new int[Preferences.DetectionArea.width() * Preferences.DetectionArea.height()];
            Preferences.gDetectionBitmapIntPrev = new int[Preferences.DetectionArea.width() * Preferences.DetectionArea.height()];

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void SetDetectionArea(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        try {
            Preferences.DetectionArea = new Rect(x, y, w, h);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void DrawAreaBox(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            if (this.getRootView().isInEditMode()) {
                super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
                return;
            }

            //Preferences.DetectionAreaOrient = UtilGeneralHelper.GetDetectRectByOrientation();

            canvas.drawColor(0);
            mPath.reset();

            canvas.drawRect(Preferences.DetectionArea, BoxPaint);

            mPath.moveTo(Preferences.DetectionArea.right - ArrowWidth, Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom);
            mPath.lineTo(Preferences.DetectionArea.right, Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom - ArrowWidth);
            mPath.lineTo(Preferences.DetectionArea.right, Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom);
            mPath.lineTo(Preferences.DetectionArea.right - ArrowWidth, Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom);
            mPath.close();
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, ArrowPaint);

            mPath.reset();
            //canvas.drawRect(Preferences.DetectionAreaOrient, BoxPaint2);
            //canvas.drawRect(Preferences.DetectionAreaOrientPort, BoxPaint2);

            TextPaint.setTextSize(16);
            TextPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.bwff));

            TextPaint.getTextBounds(getResources().getString(R.string.str_detectarea), 0, 1, mRect);
            canvas.drawText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_detectarea),
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.left + 4,
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.top + 4 + mRect.height(),
                    TextPaint);
            int recH = mRect.height();

            TextPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.2f);
            TextPaint.setTextSize(18);
            TextPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.redD_9e));
            TextPaint.getTextBounds(getResources().getString(R.string.str_dragandmove), 0, 1, mRect);
            canvas.drawText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_dragandmove),
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.left + 4,
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.top + 20 + mRect.height()*2,
                    TextPaint);

            TextPaint.getTextBounds(getResources().getString(R.string.str_scalearea), 0, 1, mRect);
            canvas.drawText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_scalearea),
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.left + 4,
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.top + 36 + mRect.height()*3,
                    TextPaint);

            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            //canvas.restore();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            invalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean retValue = true;
        int X = (int)event.getX();
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        //AppMain.txtLoc.setText(String.valueOf(X) + ", " + String.valueOf(Y));

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mBoxTouched = TouchedInBoxArea(X, Y);

                //AppMain.txtLoc.setText("BoxTouched: " + String.valueOf(mBoxTouched));

                if (!mBoxTouched) break;

                lastX = X;
                lastY = Y;

                BoxPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                BoxPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.redD_9e));

                mArrowTouched = TouchedInArrow(X, Y);
                //AppMain.txtLoc.setText("ArrowTouched: " + String.valueOf(mBoxTouched));

                if (mArrowTouched) {
                    ArrowPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.bwff_9e));
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!mBoxTouched) break;

                int moveX = X - lastX;
                int moveY = Y - lastY;

                //AppMain.txtLoc.setText("Move X, Y: " + String.valueOf(moveX) + "," + String.valueOf(moveY));
                if (!mArrowTouched) {
                    if (Preferences.DetectionArea.left + moveX < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
//              if (Preferences.DetectionArea.right + moveX > Preferences.gDisplay.getWidth()) {
//                  break;
//              }
                    // ver 2.5.9
                    if (Preferences.DetectionArea.right + moveX > Width) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (Preferences.DetectionArea.top + moveY < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
//              if (Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom + moveY > Preferences.gDisplay.getHeight()) {
//                  break;
//              }
                    // ver 2.5.9
                    if (Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom + moveY > Height) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mArrowTouched) {
                    if ((Preferences.DetectionArea.width() + moveX) < ArrowWidth * 2){
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((Preferences.DetectionArea.height() + moveY) < ArrowWidth * 2) {
                        break;
                    }
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.right += moveX;
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom += moveY;
                    //Log.i("DBG", "W,H: " + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.width()) + "," + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.height()));
                } else {
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.left += moveX;
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.right += moveX;
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.top += moveY;
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom += moveY;
                }

                lastX = X;
                lastY = Y;

                //AppMain.txtLoc.setText(String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.left) + ", " + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.top));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mBoxTouched = false;
                mArrowTouched = false;
                //BoxPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                BoxPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                BoxPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.bwff_60));
                ArrowPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.redDD));
                //AppMain.txtLoc.setText(String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.left) + ", " + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.top));

                if (Preferences.DetectionArea.left < 0) {
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.left = 0;
                }
//          if (Preferences.DetectionArea.right > Preferences.gDisplay.getWidth()) {
//              Preferences.DetectionArea.right = Preferences.gDisplay.getWidth();
//          }
                // ver 2.5.9
                if (Preferences.DetectionArea.right > Width) {
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.right = Width;
                }
                if (Preferences.DetectionArea.top < 0) {
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.top = 0;
                }
//          if (Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom > Preferences.gDisplay.getHeight()) {
//              Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom = Preferences.gDisplay.getHeight();
//          }
                if (Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom > Height) {
                    Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom = Height;
                }

                Preferences.gDetectionBitmapInt = new int[Preferences.DetectionArea.width() * Preferences.DetectionArea.height()];
                Preferences.gDetectionBitmapIntPrev = new int[Preferences.DetectionArea.width() * Preferences.DetectionArea.height()];
                //Preferences.gDetectionBitmapInt = null;
                //Preferences.gDetectionBitmapIntPrev = null;

                String area = String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.left)
                        + "," + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.top)
                        + "," + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.right)
                        + "," + String.valueOf(Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom);

               // UtilGeneralHelper.SavePreferenceSetting(Preferences.gContext, Preferences.PREF_DETECTION_AREA_KEY, area);

                break;
        }


        invalidate();
        return retValue;
    }

    private boolean TouchedInBoxArea(int x, int y) {
        boolean retValue = false;
        try {

            if (x > Preferences.DetectionArea.left && x < Preferences.DetectionArea.right) {
                if (y > Preferences.DetectionArea.top && y < Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom) {
                    retValue = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    private boolean TouchedInArrow(int x, int y) {
        boolean retValue = false;
        try {

            if (x > Preferences.DetectionArea.right - ArrowWidth && x < Preferences.DetectionArea.right) {
                if (y > Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom - ArrowWidth && y < Preferences.DetectionArea.bottom) {
                    retValue = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        InitDetectionArea();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount()-1; i++){
            (this.getChildAt(i)).layout(l, t, r, b);
        }

        if (changed) {
            // check width height
            if (r != Width || b != Height) {
                // size does not match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide your xml file because something is wrong in your xml

Comment: I have updated the xml

Comment: can you please provide your package name of AreaDetectorView

Comment: @anddevmanu Katharina's answer fixed the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `mContext`is null - you need to set `mContext = context` in your constructors.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the crashing. But the view is not looking like I wanted. I'm trying to make a motion detection app and this view is intended to inflate on top of a surface view to define the area of detection. Now all I can see is this custom view.

Comment: @DioptrePic could you provide a more detailed information about what it looks like? It's easier to search for the problem then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BoxPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bwff_60));
```

color only apply when you added in 
**your-project\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml** file.